# using date_format in fetch url variable in smarty

Tags: smarty, date-formatting

`{$GLOBALS.settings.listing_last_updated_date}` gets date from db in format

Aug 4, 2016

I need date output as `|date_format:"%m.%d.%Y"` ie. `08.04.2016`

```
{fetch file="http://`$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST`/latest/?action=search&activation_date[not_less]=`$GLOBALS.settings.listing_last_updated_date|date_format:"%m.%d.%Y"`" assign='last_updated_date'}
```

Wherever I use `{$last_updated_date}` I should get fetched content from  http://mysite/latest/?action=search&activation_date[not_less]=08.04.2016

The actual problem is using date format `|date_format:"%m.%d.%Y"` is not working in fetch variable.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way, Try to generate the date in a separated variable and then add it to the url:

```
{$last_update=$GLOBALS.settings.listing_last_updated_date|date_format:"%m.%d.%Y"}
{fetch file="http://`$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST`/latest/?action=search&activation_date[not_less]="|cat:$last_update assign='last_updated_date'}
```

Comment: not works: {$last_update=$GLOBALS.settings.listing_last_updated_date|date_format:"%m.%d.%Y"}
{$last_update}         

Fatal error: Smarty error: [in search_results_new.tpl line 7]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $last_update=$GLOBALS.settings.listing_last_updated_date|date_format:"%m.%d.%Y" (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 439) in E:\Documents\Server\htdocs\system\ext\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1095

Comment: are you using smarty 2?